# How should I do to get a UIView instance rotation angle when it is in rotation animation status?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I want to do a demo like the game called aa. So I need to get the real-time angle about the view rotation. The following codes just can obtain final angel：

```
CGFloat rotationAngle = atan2f(_view.transform.b, _view.transform.a);
CGFloat degreeAngle = rotationAngle * (180 / M_PI);
```

In my mind, if I can know coordinates of the point insert pin during the central view is rotation, I maybe finish this demo. For example,this point can make like this：

[image]

So I want to know how to rotate the view of the current has obtained is how many degrees, or other way to realize game aa.

Comment: halfer, thanks for your edtion about my question! I am a novice for using stackoverflow, I don't know to some points of ask for question need to pay attention to. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After some times testing, these codes can solve this problem:

```
- (CGFloat)transformAngleWithRotationDirection:(BOOL)clockwise {
    return clockwise ? [self transformRotationAngle] : 2.0f * M_PI - [self transformRotationAngle];
}

- (CGFloat)transformRotationAngle {
    CGFloat degreeAngle = - atan2f(self.presentationLayer.transform.m21, self.presentationLayer.transform.m22);

    if (degreeAngle < 0.0f) {
        degreeAngle += (2.0f * M_PI);
    }

    return degreeAngle;
}
```